# Using CountIf in VBA with visible cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a `CountIf` function in vba on visible cells to count all the visible cells that are `yes`, there are 25 but I get the error

> Unable to get the `CountIf` property of the `WorksheetFunction` class

and it highlights `returnCount`, not sure if there is also an error with `myrange`, any help would be much appreciated.

```
Set myrange = _
Range("D4",Range("D4").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

returnCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrange, "yes")
```

Comment: You are trying to use COUNTIF on a potentially non contiguous range of cells

Comment: Applicaiton.cointif returns type mismatch

Comment: Yes, same for me, sorry it was a number left over in my immediate window, so thought had given count.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

COUNTIF does not like non contiguous or multi-range ranges.  So iterate the areas in the range

```
Dim myrange As Range
Dim ar As Range
Set myrange = _
Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each ar In myrange.Areas
    returncount = returncount + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ar, "yes")
Next ar
```

Comment: Nice workaround, hadn't considered this -- always forget how useful `Areas` can be

Comment: REALLY nice use of `Areas` to minimize loop time.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! Will accept as the answer when I can

Comment: I was unaware of Areas. I will need to do some reading me thinks. +1

Comment: I think we all took something away from this. Thanks

Comment: @Scott Craner, the issue here is because `SpecialCells` returns multiple ranges which is not supported by `COUNTIF`. So saying that "COUNTIF does not like non contiguous ranges" is not accurate since providing contiguous ranges also raise the error: `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A5,A6:A10"), "yes")`.

Comment: @michael but special cells groups all contiguous visible cells into areas.  so in this instance they are not contiguous, and therefor for this specific purpose it works.  But yes you are correct COUNTIFS does not like multiple ranges in the range area.