# Make CountIf function only count visible cells in a range (in application.worksheetfunction)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, countif

I am tracking defects per operator per week (including the previous 5 weeks). I start with a data table at the top of the screen, which I get a list of unique employee names from (put in Column T).

I then filter the list by each employee name to view their defects over 6 weeks. If the operator has defects from the current week (Column I) (current week value stored in variable: weekNumber), then I copy the data 20 rows down and paste it, create a new table from the pasted data, then create a pivot table from the employee's new, pasted table & place the Pivot Table underneath.

[image: Example of Desired Result]

Now, I'm having trouble when it comes to only copy & pasting the data which contains a Week value of [weekNumber]. Currently, weekNumber = 41. So I only want data copied and pasted for employees that have at least one defect in Week 41. But when I select my range to COUNTIF, it includes filtered/invisible cells so if any employee has a defect in Week 41, then every employee's defects are being copied and pasted.

[image: Example of what I DON'T want]

This is my current code:

```
Sub FilterEASouthEve()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim tbl As ListObject
   Dim tbl2 As ListObject
   Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, cell2 As Range
   Dim rngT As Range
   Dim rngN As Range
   Dim filteredData As Range
   Dim destRange As Range
   Dim lastRowN As Long
   Dim lastRowT As Long
   Dim filterValue As Variant
   Dim rngWeek6 As Range
   Dim weekNumber As Integer
    
    'gets week number from first sheet to store in variable
    Sheets("All1700Defects").Select
    weekNumber = Range("S22").Value

    'creates table from data on EAS Eve sheet
    Sheets("EA SOUTH - EVE").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("a1", Cells(Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).Row, "Q:Q")), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table65"
    Range("Table65[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table65").Name = "EASouthEve"

   ' Set the worksheet and table
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EA SOUTH - EVE")
   Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("EASouthEve")

   ' Define the range for Col T (unique employee names), which is used as criteria for filtering the table by employee name
   Set rngT = ws.Range("T2:T" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row)

    'loop thru each cell in Column T, starting at T2
    For Each cell In rngT
    
        'check if the cell is not empty
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            
            'get value to filter by
            filterValue = cell.Value
    
        
            ' Apply the filter
            tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=filterValue, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            
            'set range for Week column
            Set rngWeek6 = ws.Range("I2", Selection.End(xlDown))
         
            ' Determine the destination range
            lastRowN = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
            Set destRange = ws.Cells(lastRowN + 20, "A")
         
            'determines if employee has any defects in current week
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngWeek6, weekNumber) > 0 Then
            
                ' Paste the filtered data below the table with 10-row separation
                Range("EASouthEve[[#Headers],[Date]]").Select
                 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
                 Selection.Copy
                destRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
                Set rng = Selection
                
                Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
                
                MakePivotTableFromSelection
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    'turn table filters off
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("EASOUTHEve").Range.AutoFilter Field:=14
    
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
  
End Sub
```

I have tried changing my range (rngWeek6) to:

```
Set rngWeek6 = ws.Range("I2", Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

but I get "Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the Countif property of the WorksheetFunction class"

I'm very new to VBA & have hit a wall. Please help if you can.

Comment: Hitting a wall -> first thing to do is google: [see this question and Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097017/using-countif-in-vba-with-visible-cells)

Comment: What happens when you use `ws.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(" & rngWeek6.Address & ",ROW(" & rngWeek6.Address & ")-MIN(ROW(" & rngWeek6.Address & ")),,1))*(" & rngWeek6.Address & "=" & weekNumber & "))")` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngWeek6, weekNumber)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout: i changed the IF statement to ```` If ws.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(" & rngWeek6.Address & ",ROW(" & rngWeek6.Address & ")-MIN(ROW(" & rngWeek6.Address & ")),,1))*(" & rngWeek6.Address & "=" & weekNumber & "))") > 0 Then```` and got a Type Mismatch error

Comment: @Notus_Panda: Hmm, that seems to fulfill the condition I need. Although now it goes through the loop and pastes one table for each defect meeting criteria.. So different issue now, but a step closer for sure.

Comment: That' stange. I tested it and it works. In the immediate window check what is the value of  `rngWeek6.Address` and `weekNumber`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: (not tested.....)

```
'After selecting the range:
'set range for Week column
            Set rngWeek6 = ws.Range("I2", Selection.End(xlDown))

'add the following
Dim countWeek As Integer
countWeek = 0
For Each cell2 In rngWeek6.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If cell2.Value = weekNumber Then
        countWeek = countWeek + 1
    End If
Next cell2

'then replace
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngWeek6, weekNumber) > 0 Then

'with:
If countWeek > 0 Then
```